# Two methods with the same signature except for optional parameter

Tags: c#, overloading, optional-parameters

I have been working on my project and inadvertently wrote two methods with the same signature except for optional parameters. To my surprise, the code compiles normally.

```
public async Task<List<CategoryApiModel>> GetCategoriesAsync( int contentLanguageId = 0 )
{
    ...
}

public async Task<List<CategoryApiModel>> GetCategoriesAsync( string languageTag = "" )
{
    ...
}
```

I know, that when called with empty parameters this will cause the call to be ambiguous, but I am surprised this is even allowed as a declaration itself. Could someone please explain, why is that so?

Comment: See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Comment: What happened when you tested?

Comment: see my answer for a workaround on this... although I would not recommend it, as it is kind of a code smell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will definitely compile normally because you changed the type of the input parameter as String in the second method , this also comes into the signature of a method.This will perform method overloading.
Hope this answer your question.

Comment: But does this make any sense? I mean you cannot call the method without parameters, right? Which one will be chosen then?

Comment: @lorenzalbert No it doesn't make sense and the compiler will error with an ambiguous call, however both methods can still be used if the "optional" parameter is filled in and so should still legally be allowed to be called if the parameter is passed.

Comment: @lorenzalbert If you try to call method without giving any parameter then normally it will give you compilation error of no such method declared. in the code above there is no method without parameter. hope this will clear you confusion. :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually your program compiles normally **until you have at least one GetCategoriesAsync() call**. Then you will get "error CS0121: The call is ambiguous".

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I noticed. What surprised me is that the code compiles when this call is not there.

Comment: Without the ambiguous call the code is valid. It might look weird in your case, but it make sense when you have several parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue and there will be a compilation error, but only when some code actually tries to use one of the methods with ambiguous parameters.

This could be useful (if possibly sloppy and confusing) if you had say two files, each one defining one of those two functions. If only one were in scope, then the default parameter could get used, and wouldn't be ambiguous to the compiler. But of course this could be considered sloppy because it might lead to a mistake that might not get noticed.

Comment: It is not a compiler error is it does not happen until run time.

Comment: @Frisbee So you're saying you don't get Compiler Error CS0121  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky5f1hz8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx  ?

Comment: This will happen during compile time, if the method is called without parameters

Comment: I assumed the OP had a call with no parameter in the program.

Answer (score 1):

The code will compile fine because both `overloads` can be called separately by passing the correct parameter into them.

```
GetCategoriesAsync(1);
```

So for obvious reasons the code will work.

However if there is a call made, like so: `GetCategoriesAsync()`, it now throws a compilation error of:

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous

The reason being it stated clearly in the error message, there is no best match for the method as it can easily fit both.

Whats interesting to note is that if there is an empty overload to the function i.e.

```
public async Task<List<CategoryApiModel>> GetCategoriesAsync()
{}
```

The code will compile because it will use that call. So the problem can be diverted by doing something like the following:

```
public async Task<List<CategoryApiModel>> GetCategoriesAsync()
{
     return GetCategoriesAsync(0);
}
```

Although I would not recommend it.

Comment: Why does the compiler prefer parameterless method over the one with an optional parameter? I find it confusing, there should be an exception thrown, in my opinion.

Comment: P.S. I see a great link above https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Overloading, it doesn't clarify why exactly such an approach has been chosen though.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use the behaviour of 'No Parameters' for both methods, by passing the default value of the correct type.

E.g.:
`GetCategoriesAsync(0)` for the first method call.
`GetCategoriesAsync("")` for the second method call.
So, the behaviour would be same as you don't pass the parameter, since you are passing the default value (Please note, the default value is not the default value of the type, but the default value manually set within the method, if the parameter is not provided)